# How to store Alternate Names for Places or City in Table

Tags: mysql, database-design

What is best way to store Alternate Names of the Places (City or Locality) in MySQL database columns which user will be searching?

Examples:
In India user may search for "Chennai" or "Madras" and both are same City.
And "Sanjeeva Reddy Nagar" or "SR Nagar" are same Locality in Hyderabad City that user may search for.

```
Properties
-----------
PropertyId INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PropertyName VARCHAR(64),
City VARCHAR(32),
Locality VARCHAR(32)
```

So in above structure how shall we accomodate alternate names for City and Locality?

- Option-1:

  May be having 2 more columns (AlternateCity, AlternateLocality) and have search function search in both the columns (Ex: if user search for Locality then it will search in Locality and AlternateLocality column)
- Option-2:

  May be having the same column store multiple data values in one column. Ex: City can store "Chennai (Madras)" and search can use Like operator?

What is the best way to store these data knowing one place may have 2 - 3 names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The normalised way would be create a master table for town and then create another table for alternate names with a 1 to many relationship. This allows you to have 0..N alternate names. To fully normalise it you would pull all the names out from the town table and put them into the town names table and have a flag which denotes the default or primary name and locality for that town or you could go even further and have a name type column allowing you to further define the name type in a meaningful way.

This happens a lot with names and addresses for people. People have a primary (or legal name) and they also have one or more aliases or other known-as names and the technique of separating the name from the actual person and categorising their name via a type is commonly used - the same for their addresses

Comment: Thanks @James for the answer, but in our case it will be a single denormalized table that the API will be hitting to so we need to think if we really need to go for another master/detail table.

Comment: You can expose the able via the API in a denormalised way. It would be very simple to concatenate the various entries to give you a single line result string.

Comment: What the database does needn't be (shouldn't be!) exposed to the API.

Comment: In my scenario modifying API or having a master detail table are not the Options. So I will have to think of having the data stored into the single table only. I know it is not good to store in same table but in some situation we need to adjust as needed.

Comment: @Prabhat if you don't have a great degree of flexibility then I would go with option two if you are likely to need more than one alternate. You will have to keep an eye on the performance of the like query. If you structure the data properly and use some form of delimitation you could split the values into a temp table which may be worth exploring if there is lots of alternate names per town.

Comment: The API should hit _code_ that will turn around and hit the _database_.  This code can do whatever `JOINs`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, etc that is needed to accommodate the underlying schema.  To elaborate on Phil's statement -- _Hide_ the schema from the front end.

Comment: At present I have just one alternative name for some of the places so may be we can just go with Option-1 and have another column with alternateName and my API will be modified to include OR Condition to check this new column as well. Thoughts? @James, I agree with you for the Like query issues.